# How do I create a url link depending on what state I have in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a query link that is created based on the state of the component. When user selects an option the states are changed and then user can select 'search' button. The query on the search button should however be according to the states that were changed by the user.
For eg.

```
/rent/?bedrooms=1&bathrooms=1
/rent/?bedrooms=2&parking=1
```

```js
const FilterOption = () => {
  const [postCode, setPostCode] = useState();
  const [price, setPrice] = useState();
  const [bedroomCount, setBedroomCount] = useState(0);    
  const [bathroomCount, setBathroomCount] = useState(0);
  const [parkingCount, setParkingCount] = useState(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook to take the current state values and update the URL search params.

Example:

```js
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const FilterOption = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const [postCode, setPostCode] = useState();
  const [price, setPrice] = useState();

  const [bedroomCount, setBedroomCount] = useState(
    Number(searchParams.get("bedrooms") ?? 0)
  );
  const [bathroomCount, setBathroomCount] = useState(
    Number(searchParams.get("bathrooms") ?? 0)
  );
  const [parkingCount, setParkingCount] = useState(
    Number(searchParams.get("parking") ?? 0)
  );

  const searchHandler = () => {
    setSearchParams(searchParams => {
      searchParams.set("bedrooms", bedroomCount);
      searchParams.set("bathrooms", bathroomCount);
      searchParams.set("parking", parkingCount);
      return searchParams;
    });
  };

  ...
}
```

If you need a little more control over the search params you can check the counts and remove params where the count is 0.

```js
const searchHandler = () => {
  setSearchParams(searchParams => {
    if (bedroomCount) {
      searchParams.set("bedrooms", bedroomCount);
    } else {
      searchParams.delete("bedrooms");
    }
    if (bathroomCount) {
      searchParams.set("bathrooms", bathroomCount);
    } else {
      searchParams.delete("bathrooms");
    }
    if (parkingCount) {
      searchParams.set("parking", parkingCount);
    } else {
      searchParams.delete("parking");
    }

    return searchParams;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the code inside setSearchParams function call is not reachable. 

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
     setSearchParams(searchParams => {
           // code not reachable
    });      
  }

Comment: @Clippit Welcome, glad to help, but can you clarify how the code in the `setSearchParams` is unreachable? The callback version of `setSearchParams` was a later addition, what specific version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: Thanks I updated my 'react-router-dom'  to latest version and its now working.

Comment: Is there any way to use 'useNavigate' with 'useSearchParams'. I am trying to get my url to look like '/rent/newyork/?bedrooms=1' or '/rent/california/?bedrooms=1' based on location. I believe 'createSearchParams' as per this blog https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/navigate-to-url-query-strings-search-params-react-router is better suited for my use-case. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Clippit You *might* be able to use both `navigate` and `setSearchParams`, but yeah, you may be better off using `useSearchParams` to get the current `searchParams` object and then use `navigate`, something like `navigate({ pathname: "....", search: searchParams.toString() })` after you have set the search param values.

Answer (score 0):

instead of query params can you use the react router state?  something like

```
const routeState = {
    postCode,
    price,
    bedroomCount,
    bathroomCount,
    parkingCount,
};
<Link to={{ pathname: "/your-destination-route", state: routeState }}>Go to Details</Link>
```

then to use it.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
 const { postCode, price, bedroomCount, bathroomCount, parkingCount } = location.state || {};
```